# What is the difference between access method in controller and custom access check

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

I am trying to create a module with custom access checks.

I would like to know what additional features does implementing AccessInterface provide.

For example I can check access within the controller using access method.

But there is also a way to create a separate access checker file as below.

My Code is as follows what difference does both have.

## access_check_examples.routing.yml

```
access_check_examples.build:
  path: '/examples-codes/access-check-examples/build'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Access Check Build Controller'
    _controller: '\Drupal\access_check_examples\Controller\AccessCheckController::build'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\access_check_examples\Controller\AccessCheckController::access'

access_check_examples.info:
  path: '/examples-codes/access-check-examples/info'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Access Check Info Controller'
    _controller: '\Drupal\access_check_examples\Controller\AccessCheckController::info'
  requirements:
    _custom_role_access_check: 'TRUE'
```

## AccessCheckController.php

```
namespace Drupal\access_check_examples\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Returns responses for Access Check routes.
 */
class AccessCheckController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Builds the response.
   */
  public function build() {

    $build['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('It works!'),
    ];

    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * Builds the response.
   */
  public function info() {

    $build['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('It works!'),
    ];

    return $build;
  }


  /**
   * Checks access for a specific request.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {

    $uid = $account->id();
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->hasPermission('administer access check examples configuration') && $uid == 1);
  }

}
```

## access_check_examples.services.yml

```
services:
  access_check.access_check_examples.custom_role_access_check:
    class: Drupal\access_check_examples\Access\CustomRoleAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@database','@messenger','@logger.factory','@date.formatter']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _custom_role_access_check }
```

## CustomRoleAccessCheck.php

```
namespace Drupal\access_check_examples\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;


/**
 * Checks if the route has required permission.
 *
 */
class CustomRoleAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

    /**
   * Database connection.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   */
  protected $database;

  /**
   * Date formatter.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface
   */
  protected $dateFormatter;

  /**
   * The Messenger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface
   */
  protected $messenger;

  /**
   * Logger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $logger;

  /**
   * UserLoginSubscriber constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection $database
   *   The database service.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface $messenger
   *   The messenger service.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger
   *   The logger service.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter $date_formatter
   *   The date formatter service.
   */
  public function __construct(Connection $database, MessengerInterface $messenger, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger, DateFormatter $date_formatter) {
    $this->database = $database;
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
    $this->logger = $logger->get('access_check_examples');
    $this->dateFormatter = $date_formatter;

  }

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route
   *   The route to check against.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function access(Route $route,AccountInterface $account) {

    if (!$route->hasRequirement('_custom_role_access_check')) {
      return AccessResult::neutral();
    }

    $uid = $account->id();
     $this->messenger->addMessage(t('Your UID is :  %uid', ['%uid' => $uid]), 'notice');

    $this->logger->notice('Your UID is :  @uid', ['@uid' => $uid]);

    return AccessResult::allowedIf(!$account->hasPermission('administer access check examples configuration') && $uid == 1)->addCacheContexts(['route']);
  }


}
```

There is a similar [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201328) in regards but can not get required info from there. Can anyone please provide the differences between both.

Comment: Access checks are always placed in tagged services. Drupal core provides [CustomAccessCheck](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CustomAccessCheck.php/class/CustomAccessCheck/9.0.x), which is tagged the same way, for convenient reasons so that a simple module is able to provide content and access checks in a single controller class. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221891/how-do-you-set-a-one-off-access-checker-on-a-route

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. You seem to be asking what a custom access controller is, but you've already created one, so I can't understand why you wouldn't know what that is.

Comment: Hi @Jaypan , I wanted to know why there are two ways to implement access check and what is difference between  the both.

Comment: Hi @4k4 , Thank you for the response, so basically controller has access method for convenient purpose but actually it is also a derivative of tagged service right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the service  CustomAccessCheck you call through  `_custom_access` has no access method of its own but instantiates the controller to run the access method you have specified.

Comment: HI @4k4 Thank you for clarifying.